# Iterate in 2 steps with `IntStream`

Tags: java

Here's my code:

```
    List<UserModel> reversed = Lists.reverse(Arrays.asList(new UserModel("userId1"), new UserModel("userId2"), new UserModel("userId3"), new UserModel("userId4"));
    List<UserPairModel> result = nwe LinkedList<>();
    IntStream.range(0, reversed.size())
            .filter(idx -> idx % 2 == 0)
            .forEach(idx -> {
                        UserModel userModel1 = null;
                        UserModel userModel2 = null;
                        try {
                            userModel1 = reversed.get(idx - 1);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // do nothing
                        }
                        try {
                            userModel2 = reversed.get(idx);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // do nothing
                        }
                        result.add(UserPairModel.from(userModel1, userModel2));
                    }
            );
    return Lists.reverse(result);
}
```

The goal is to pair two `UserModel` into one `UserPairModel` the source list, `reversed` may contain zero, one or more elements.

If the source list contains no element: the output would be a `result` list with one `UserPairModel` constructed by something like, `UserPairModel.from(null, null)`

If the source list contains only one element then similarly, the `result` list would contain one `UserPairModel` which built like this, `UserPairModel.from(notNull, null)`, essentially what is being achieved here it to pair any number of `UserModel` by two's.

The problem with this code, given the four (4) elements (*userId1, userId2, userId3, userId4*), only the last 3 elements are stored in the `result` List, i.e. 2,3, and 4, skipping the first element.

Comment: Why eben try with stands? This seems like the most natural use for a counting `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IntStream.range(0, reversed.size())
            .filter(idx -> idx % 2 == 0)
            .forEach(idx -> {
                UserModel userModel1 = reversed.get(idx);
                UserModel userModel2 = idx + 1 < reversed.size() ? reversed.get(idx + 1) : null;
                result.add(UserPairModel.from(userModel1, userModel2));
            });
```

Or to put it in more readable form:

```
for (int idx = 0; idx < reversed.size(); idx += 2) {
    UserModel userModel1 = reversed.get(idx);
    UserModel userModel2 = idx + 1 < reversed.size() ? reversed.get(idx + 1) : null;
    result.add(UserPairModel.from(userModel1, userModel2));
}
```